# Getting " ISO C++ forbids declaration ..." error.?

Tags: c++, syntax-error

The following code is just a part of my Header file

```
    double calculateDistance(const wp, &CWaypoint);
    void print(int format);
    bool less(wp_right, const &CWaypoint); 
    CWaypoint add(wp_right, const &CWaypoint);
```

The error is:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\Waypoint.o ..\src\Waypoint.cpp
In file included from ..\src\Waypoint.cpp:15:0:
..\src\/Waypoint.h:45:33: error: 'wp' does not name a type
..\src\/Waypoint.h:45:33: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'parameter' with no type
..\src\/Waypoint.h:47:12: error: 'wp_right' has not been declared
..\src\/Waypoint.h:48:16: error: 'wp_right' has not been declared
```

P.S. : I am a C++ beginner

Comment: Your title shows only part of the error message. Please show us the *entire* message in the body of your question.

Comment: g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\Waypoint.o ..\src\Waypoint.cpp
In file included from ..\src\Waypoint.cpp:15:0:
..\src\/Waypoint.h:45:33: error: 'wp' does not name a type
..\src\/Waypoint.h:45:33: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'parameter' with no type
..\src\/Waypoint.h:47:12: error: 'wp_right' has not been declared
..\src\/Waypoint.h:48:16: error: 'wp_right' has not been declared

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean

```
double calculateDistance(const wp, CWaypoint&);
```

etc.

`&` is placed after the type not before. You maybe have other errors, it's hard to be sure. Normally I would would both the type and the variable name in a function prototype, although the variable name is optional.

OK based in the code in the comments below it seems you want

```
class CWaypoint
{
...
    double calculateDistance(const CWaypoint& wp); 
    void print(int format); 
    bool less(const CWaypoint& wp_right);
    CWaypoint add(const CWaypoint& wp_right);
};
```

I'm not sure why you put the parameter name before the type, or why you separated the parameter name and type with a comma. You had done it correctly with the other methods like getAllDataByPointer and getAllDataByReference.

The rule is that commas separate method parameters, so if your method takes a single parameter there should be no comma, and if it takes two there should be one comma between the two parameter declarations, etc.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do;  class CWaypoint
{
private:
 string m_name;
 double m_latitude;
 double m_longitude;
 void transformLongitude2degmmss(int &deg, int &mm, double &ss);
 void transformLatitude2degmmss(int &deg, int &mm, double &ss);

Comment: public:
 CWaypoint(string name, double latitude, double longitude);
 void set(string name, double latitude, double longitude);
 string getName();
 double getLatitude();
 double getLongitude();
 void getAllDataByPointer(string *pname,double *platitude, double *plongitude);
 void getAllDataByReference(string &pname,double &platitude, double &plongitude);
 double calculateDistance(const wp, CWaypoint&);
 void print(int format);
 bool less(wp_right, const CWaypoint&);
 CWaypoint add(wp_right, const CWaypoint&);
};

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 errors in your function declaration. First error that reported by `gcc` is: `wp` have no type: you say `const wp`, OK `wp` is a constant, but wait constant of what??

Second error is you place `&` before the type and that's an error too.

Third, you place name of argument before it type, so in the end you should have:

```
double calculateDistance(const CWaypoint& wp);
bool less(const CWaypoint& wp_right);
```